# Can I make this Twig code simpler?

Tags: php, twig

```
{% if app.request.locale=='en' %} {{ amenity.name }} {% endif %}
{% if app.request.locale=='de' %} {{ amenity.namede }} {% endif %}
{% if app.request.locale=='it' %} {{ amenity.nameit }} {% endif %}
{% if app.request.locale=='es' %} {{ amenity.namees }} {% endif %}
```

Is there any way to write this code better?

Comment: Yes, you can pass a lookup array with `app.request.locale` being the key and simply look it up that way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this

```
{% set map = {
    'en' : 'name',
    'de' : 'namede',
    'it' : 'nameit',
    'es' : 'namees',
} %}

{{ attribute(amenity, map[app.request.locale] }}
```